# sbt get real compiler options in custom sbt plugin

Tags: scala, sbt

I know there is `scalacOptions` in sbt. But options add via `addCompilerPlugin` does not exists in `scalacOptions`.

I type `show scalacOptions` in sbt console and there is nothing like `-Xplugin`.

So how can I get `real` scalac options when I am writing an sbt plugin

My sbt info

```
> libraryDependencies
[info] List(org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.4, org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.10.4, io.netty:netty:3.9.0.Final, net.sandrogrzicic:scalabuff-runtime:1.3.7, org.scalamacros:quasiquotes:2.0.0, org.specs2:specs2:2.3.11:test, org.scalamacros:paradise:2.0.0:plugin->default(compile))
> show scalacOptions
[info] List(-feature, -deprecation, -language:implicitConversions, -language:dynamics)
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jul 3, 2014 4:04:09 PM
> version
[info] 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
> sbt
sbtBinaryVersion    sbtClearOnFailure   sbtDependency       sbtPlugin           sbtPopOnFailure     sbtResolver         sbtStashOnFailure   
> sbtVersion
[info] 0.13.5
>
```

my build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % "2.10.4",
  "io.netty" % "netty" % "3.9.0.Final",
  "net.sandrogrzicic" %% "scalabuff-runtime" % "1.3.7",
  "org.scalamacros" %% "quasiquotes" % "2.0.0",
  "org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "2.3.11" % "test")

scalacOptions ++= Seq(
  "-feature",
  "-deprecation",
  "-language:implicitConversions",
  "-language:dynamics"
)

parallelExecution in Test := false

addCompilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.0.0" cross CrossVersion.full)
```

Comment: I glad to see that I'm not the only one who get bunch of troubles with sbt. It just have no documentation, so make git clone of the project and try to track source code inside ./main/src/main/scala/sbt/Defaults.scala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found `compile:scalacOptions` actually contains the plugin settings

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have actually managed to add the compiler plugin?

With sbt 0.13.5 and an empty project with this in build.sbt:

```
addCompilerPlugin("org.scala-lang.plugins" % "continuations" % "2.10.1")
```

I get the plugin in both libraryDependencies and scalacOptions:

```
> libraryDependencies
[info] List(org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.4, org.scala-lang.plugins:continuations:2.10.1:plugin->default(compile))
> show scalacOptions
[info] List(-Xplugin:/Users/johan/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang.plugins/continuations/jars/continuations-2.10.1.jar)
```

Comment: I have update my question, can you take a look at it.

Comment: And the compilerPlugin is actually run? You haven't accidently added it to project/plugins.sbt instead of build.sbt? (Compiler plugins are _not_ sbt plugins)

Comment: I am using quansiquote in scala 2.10. And it compiles well, so I guess the plugin added successfully

Comment: Then I have no idea. Looking at the sbt sources, the only thing that addCompilerPlugin does is decorating the ModuleID with a special "configuration" ("plugin->default(compile)") and then adding it to libraryDependencies, so if it works it should be there.

Comment: Yes, the library dependencies contains that as you said.

Comment: With your exact config it looks right if I leave out scalacOptions customization, could it be you found an sbt bug maybe?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56693/discussion-between-jilen-and-johanandren).